# Переименование дублей. Регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Задача состоит в том чтобы импортировать товары из XML файла, но так как такие характеристики, как тип , цвет, артикул, размер, категория идут все с пометкой "param", они все идут как массив... а не по отдельности, чтобы их можно было использовать. Поэтому я ищу способ переименовать эти дубли. Как решение, хочу переименовать их в нотпаде с помощью регулярных выражений.

В файле есть строки, где присутствует такое:

```
</description><param name="Тип">Ветровки</param><param name="Цвет">Black</param><param name="Размер">S</param><param name="Категория">женские</param><param name="Артикул">JWI61</param>
```

Comment: `/<(param)/g` — ? А найти и что с ним делать?

Comment: Так не находит. Нужно поочередно переименовать в param1, param2, param3, param4, param5

Comment: Незнаю, у меня xml файл, и я не нашел другой идеи как переименовать в нотпаде... но не могу подобрать рег выражение правильное

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/7opd03h9/ - возможно так... В верхнем поле вводится текст, подменяется при клике на кнопку. Уверен, что есть решение получше, плохо в этом разбираюсь...

Answer (score 2):

Не мучайте себя и Ваш XML файл регулярными выражениями! Используйте правильные средства.

Одно из них - модуль `xml.etree.ElementTree`

Вот как оно просто получается - смотрите ниже.

Только вот зачем Вы переименовываете тэги, этого я не могу понять. Однако, Вам, конечно же, виднее.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <item>
        <description>Test</description>
        <param name="Type">Jackets</param>
        <param name="Color">Black</param>
        <param name="Size">S</param>
        <param name="Category">Women</param>
        <param name="Code">JWI61</param>
    </item>
    <item>
        <description>Test2</description>
        <param name="Type">Caps</param>
        <param name="Color">Yellow</param>
        <param name="Size">S</param>
        <param name="Category">Women</param>
        <param name="Code">CPS123</param>
    </item>
    <item>
        <description>Test3</description>
        <param name="Type">Pants</param>
        <param name="Color">Blue</param>
        <param name="Size">S</param>
        <param name="Category">Women</param>
        <param name="Code">PTS321</param>
    </item>
</data>
'''

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)

for child in tree:
    params = child.findall('param')
    for i in range(0,5):
        params[i].tag = 'param{}'.format(i+1)

print(ET.tostring(tree, encoding='utf8', method='xml').decode())
```

На выходе:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<data>
    <item>
        <description>Test</description>
        <param1 name="Type">Jackets</param1>
        <param2 name="Color">Black</param2>
        <param3 name="Size">S</param3>
        <param4 name="Category">Women</param4>
        <param5 name="Code">JWI61</param5>
    </item>
    <item>
        <description>Test2</description>
        <param1 name="Type">Caps</param1>
        <param2 name="Color">Yellow</param2>
        <param3 name="Size">S</param3>
        <param4 name="Category">Women</param4>
        <param5 name="Code">CPS123</param5>
    </item>
    <item>
        <description>Test3</description>
        <param1 name="Type">Pants</param1>
        <param2 name="Color">Blue</param2>
        <param3 name="Size">S</param3>
        <param4 name="Category">Women</param4>
        <param5 name="Code">PTS321</param5>
    </item>
</data>
```